# SQL Server cannot be reached by name only by IP

Tags: windows, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have several computers (XP) connected to domain controller (2008R2). Last time I had to change IP address of the SQL Server 2008 R2 (simple instance, no clustering or replication). DNS has been updated and on all computers everything work great. On all computers...but one. The one computer behaves strange - I can connect to SQL Server only if I put the IP address. Using the name I get an error "SQL Server does not exist or access denied".

I checked things from troubleshouting:

- the name is resolved correctly when pinging (and ping is ok)
- connection is established when telneting
- nslookup works in both directions (ptr record set)
- \\servername works without problem

I tried releasing and renewing IP, dns flushing, restarting but with no success.

Server configuration should be ok because other computers work great and before IP change it was ok. Maybe SQL client is caching something? Do you have any ideas? Please help

Comment: Does the pc have IP 6 enabled?

Comment: @benni_mac_b No, it doesn't

Comment: Is there a SQL alias configured in the client settings on the affected machine?

Comment: @CMcKeown OMG, you are right! Aliases where the problem! Thank you a lot. Please add the answer, I will mark it as the correct answer. Btw. it is interesting who and why set it (espacially where was no SQL Configuration Manager installed before)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that there isn't a SQL Alias present in the machine's SQL Client configuration for the remote server name.

Comment: Just want to say Chris's Alias thing fixed it for me!
Thanks!